# What is the logarithmic transformation of this optimization problem?

Tags: convex-analysis, convex-optimization, nonlinear-optimization

Given $$n, C, r_i, p_i,a_i \quad∀ i={1,2,...,n} $$ I want to solve this optimization problem:
$$\text{maximize} \quad f(x_1,x_2,...,x_n)=\prod_{i=1}^n {{(x_i-a_i)}^{p_i}} $$
$$\text{s.t.} \quad {(x_i/r_i)≤1}, \quad {(\sum_{i=1}^n x_i)}/C ≤1,\quad {(a_i/x_i)≤1}$$
where 
$$0≤p_i≤1 \quad\quad,   \sum_{i=0}^n p_i =1\quad \quad\quad, ∀x_i,r_i.a_i,p_i∈R,\quad x_i,r_i,a_i>0,\quad C>0 $$ 
I want to know what is the logarithmic transformation of this problem and I want to convert it to an appropriate form to be solved by CVX.
Thank you for your help

Answer (score 1):

Minimizing a function is the same as minimizing the log, so we can transform the objective
$$\prod_{i=1}^n (x_i - a_i)^{p_i} \mapsto \log\prod_{i=1}^n (x_i - a_i)^{p_i} = \sum_{i=1}^n p_i \log(x_i - a_i),$$
which is concave since each $p_i\geq 0$.
Simple rearrangement of the denominator gives the following problem which is suitable for CVX.
$$
\begin{align*}
  \text{maximize: }& \sum_{i=1}^n p_i \log(x_i - a_i)\\
  \text{subj. to: }& a_i \leq x_i \leq r_i \text{ for all $i=1,2,\ldots,n$}\\
                   & \sum_{i=1}^n x_i \leq C.
\end{align*}
$$
Since the constraints are linear and the objective is a concave maximization, this problem is convex.